# Excel 2003 VBA - Lock Columns if date in range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to lock all the columns that have a certain date range in the headers. This code runs but just locks entire document.

Dates are in a range from B2 TO DD2 in format dd/mm/yyyy

I want to lock all columns before last Friday. So each time the spreadsheet is opened it checks current date, finds last Friday, then locks all columns in the range so edits can not be made.

Would really appreciate some assistance, my first proper go at VBA.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Data").Activate
ProtectTheSheet
End Sub

Function dteLastFriday(dte As Date) As Date
Dim x As Integer
x = Weekday(dte)
If x = 7 Then
    dteLastFriday = dte - 1
Else
    dteLastFriday = dte - 1 - x
End If
End Function

Function ProtectTheSheet()
Dim chCell As Range
Dim chRng As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Set chRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:DD2")

For Each chCell In chRng.Cells
    If chCell < dteLastFriday(Date) Then
        chCell.Locked = (chCell.Value <> "")
    End If
Next chCell

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub ProtectTheSheet()
    Dim chCell As Range
    Dim chRng As Range
    Dim lFriday As Date

    With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
        'unlock all cells
        .Cells.Locked = False
        Set chRng = .Range("B2:DD2")
        'calculate it once rather than each iteration in loop
        lFriday = dteLastFriday(Date)

        For Each chCell In chRng.Cells
            If chCell.Value < lFriday And chCell.Value <> "" Then
                chCell.EntireColumn.Locked = True 
            End If
        Next chCell

        .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```

and your function:

```
Function dteLastFriday(dte As Date) As Date
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Weekday(dte)
    If x = 7 Then
        dteLastFriday = dte - 1
    Else
        dteLastFriday = dte - 1 - x
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Brilliant works perfectly. Made one minor edit to make it include Fridays. < into <=  appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert the cell-value to a date before you compare it:

```
If CDate(chCell) < dteLastFriday(Date) Then
```

If you then want to lock the entire column:

```
chCell.EntireColumn.Locked = True
```

This test `chCell.Value <> ""` is probably always True (or always False), because you have already tested its value.

But cells are Locked by default, so you need to unlock them first:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Locked = False
```